# Match data frame content with a character and replace the match with a specific word (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I have a data frame with one column X. In addition, I have an object (ob) class (character). I would like to create a new object (ob1) were characters in ob that match df content are replaced with the word "word".

```
df
   X
1 ABC
2 ACC
3 ATT
```

```
ob

[1] "ABC", "ACC", "ATT", "AGG", "ACT"
```

result

```
ob1

[1] "word", "word", "word", "AGG", "ACT"
```

Comment: Why are some elements of `ob` separated by `,` and others not?

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining `ifelse` with `%in%` should do the job:

```
ob <- c("ABC", "ACC", "ATT", "AGG", "ACT")
df <- data.frame(x = c("ABC", "ACC", "ATT"))

ifelse(ob %in% df$x, yes = "word", no = ob)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
sapply(ob,function(x)stri_replace_all_fixed(x,df$X,"word",vectorize_all = FALSE))
   ABC    ACC    ATT    AGG    ACT 
"word" "word" "word"  "AGG"  "ACT"
```

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(X = c("ABC", "ACC", "ATT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
ob<-c("ABC", "ACC", "ATT", "AGG", "ACT")
```